# Why does my android app doesn't connect with my web service when I install it on my tablet altough it runs fine in a virtual device with froyo?

Tags: android, .net, web-services, tablet, android-2.2-froyo

I developed an android app that consumes .net web services using ksoap-2. 
The app consumes the service very well on a virtual device with android 2.2 (froyo), but when I install the apk package on a tablet with android 2.2 (froyo) the consume of the service isn't done.
I have already added the internet permission to the manifest file.
 I don't have any other ideas to make this runs on the tablet, any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked your tablet net connection, by using the browser ,...

Comment: Yes, i actually have a nice connection with my browser that's why I'm out of ideas.

Comment: What URL are you connecting to?  Are you sure it's not something your PC can resolve the route to, but your tablet cannot?

Comment: If you are using 10.0.2.2 for connecting to your localhost, you wont be able to do it in your tablet.

Comment: The services are published on a server, so I think it's not a localhost problem, Gogu.

Comment: Try to debug with real device. Don't think that real device is always better than emulator. I had issue with file transfer which works fine emulator but fail on device.

Comment: As the tablet is borrowed I think I'll do it tomorrow, thanks @Yul, I'll write the results in some hours, thank you all (:

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I'll post the answer to my problem down here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because since Android Gingerbread 2.3 they introduced a new way on consuming Web services, you're not allowed to consume a WS from the parent thread.